# Create tabbed style block indentation without creating new table style?

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve something simple like the following without creating a new css table style?  Basically have  block style indentation?

[image]

Comment: By "without creating a new css table style" do you mean that you don't want to use `display: table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use tables ?

But you can easily achieve this with floating elements, absolute positioning and a bit of margin, like e.g.

```
<ul style="float:left;">
    <li style="list-style-type:none;">Member since:</li>
    <li style="list-style-type:none;">Last visited:</li>
</ul>

<ul style="float:left;position:absolute;margin-left:120px;">
    <li style="list-style-type:none;">07-30-2009 09:45pm</li>
    <li style="list-style-type:none;">37 minutes ago</li>
</ul>

<img src="avatar.jpg" widht="50" height="50" style="float:left;position:absolute;margin-left:180px;" />
```

Comment: Edited, lists are better than divs here ;)

Comment: Anyway, I'd still suggest you use a table for this case, just because this list IS a table and there's no reason why you shouldn't make use of a css-table then! Tables are only evil as design-scaffold!